# libtasn1 not found, but I have already install it

Tags: linux, cryptography, makefile, configure, gnutls

When I configure gnutls and p11-kit, it show that "libtasn1 not found", but i have already install it. why and how to solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to link a shared library in some executable you are building,
not just make that library available to programs at runtime, then
you need to have installed its header files as well as the library itself,
so that the compiler can find them.

Therefore, when `./configure` checks for a library that you need to link,
it checks if you have the library headers as well as the library.

To get the library headers, you need to install the *development package*
of the library, not just the runtime package.

If you are using a debian-based distro, then the development package for
`libtasn1` is `libtasn1-N-dev` (for some number `N`). For RPM-based
distros it will be something on the lines of `libtasn1-devel-X.Y-Z....`

BTW, please do not post links to offsite images of text that you
want us to read. Just copy-paste the *text* in the body of your question,
indented 4 spaces. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
for details of formatting your posts.